# MT4/Wine/Ubuntu will not allow FileOpen

Tags: linux, mt4

I am trying to get MT4 to talk to Ubuntu;
code:

```
volumeCount=FileOpen(/home/david/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \ 
(x86\)/Capital\ City\ Markets\ MetaTrader\ 
4/MQL4/Files/+"Volpath.bin",FILE_READ|FILE_WRITE|FILE_BIN);}
```

This produces an error 'Illegal escape sequence'.
1. I am using wine to run this and I made sure all the permissions were good to go, but I still can't seem to get it to write.

```
   volumeCount=FileOpen("/home/david/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \ 
  (x86\)/Capital\ City\ Markets\ MetaTrader\ 
   4/MQL4/Files/Volpath.bin",FILE_READ|FILE_WRITE|FILE_BIN);}
```

This produces error 5007. I can't use the regular FileOpen sequence or it produces the same thing.

**Bottom Line**
I need FileOpen() to work in an ubuntu/wine environment.

Answer (score 0):

hi you need double backslash or use double quotes when you have a space in the name i.e mt4/Program\ Files/  or better mt4/"Program Files"/